# self.alias2op: typing.Dict[str, SQLToken] = alias2o

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I am trying to integrate mongoDB with django using djongo package, when I do `python3 manage.py migrate` am getting the following error..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/eindhan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/eindhan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/eindhan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/eindhan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/eindhan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/eindhan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/eindhan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/eindhan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 114, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/home/eindhan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 315, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home/eindhan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 205, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/home/eindhan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/home/eindhan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 202, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/eindhan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/djongo/base.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .cursor import Cursor
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .sql2mongo.query import Result
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/__init__.py", line 24
    self.alias2op: typing.Dict[str, SQLToken] = alias2op
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is my django settings

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'MyDB',
    }
}
```

Anything wrong here.. I am using standard django 1.9.2, but people are suggesting to use django-nonrel framework.

I am following this [tutorial](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NoSqlSupport)

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Check your python version to be above the requirements (taken on the comment date from https://github.com/nesdis/djongo):

Python 3.6 or higher.

MongoDB 3.4 or higher.

If your models use nested queries or sub querysets like:

```
inner_qs = Blog.objects.filter(name__contains='Ch').values('name')
entries = Entry.objects.filter(blog__name__in=inner_qs)
```

MongoDB 3.6 or higher is required.